# Return column of pandas df when another column's list contains specific value

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a df constructed as such:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {'001': [['one','two','three']],
       '002': [['two', 'five', 'eight']],
       '003': [['three','six','ten','twelve']]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic,orient='index')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.rename(columns = {'index':'id',0:'values'})
print(df)
```

The resulting df looks like

```
    id                     values
0  001          [one, two, three]
1  002         [two, five, eight]
2  003  [three, six, ten, twelve]
```

I would like to write a function that returns a dataframe or series of ids if a specific value in the corresponding list was called. For example:

```
def find_ids(value):
    ids = psuedocode: if list contains value, then return id
    return ids
```

So

```
find_ids('two')
```

should return

```
id
001
002
```

and

```
find_ids('twelve')
```

should return

```
id
003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
def find_ids(df, value):
    return df.loc[df["values"].apply(lambda x: value in x), "id"]


print(find_ids(df, "two"))
```

Prints:

```
0    001
1    002
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `.str.join(sep = " ").str.contains(value)` which first converts the `list` into `string` and then checks if generated string contains the `value`.

```
def find_ids(df, value):
   return df.loc[df['values'].str.join(sep = " ").str.contains(value), "id"]
```

Output:

```
>>> print(find_ids(df, "two"))
0    001
1    002
Name: id, dtype: object
```

---

To make it more efficient try saving list as string using `.str.join(sep = " ")` in a new column and then you can search using `.str.contains(value)`

```
df['values_str'] = df['values'].str.join(sep = " ")
def find_ids(df, value):
    return df.loc[df.values_str.str.contains(value), "id"]
```

Output:

```
>>> print(find_ids(df, "two"))
0    001
1    002
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
def find_ids(value):
    newdf=df.explode('values')
    return newdf.loc[newdf['values']==value,'id']
```

Now finally call the function:

```
print(find_ids('two'))
```

Output:

```
0    001
1    002
```